# Different approaches solving $z^{2n} = \bar{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

So I go this formula: $ z^{2n} = \bar{z} $, of course $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Me and a couple of friends tried solving for $z$, but came with different solutions, and we can't figure out exactly who's right and why.

**Approach one**

Using trigonometric notation:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\cis}{cis}
(r\cis(\theta) )^{2n} = r\cis(-\theta)
$$

And using De-Moivre: 
$$r\cis(\theta) = \sqrt[2n]{r\cis(-\theta)} = r^{1\over2n}\cis({2\pi k -\theta\over2n}), k=0,\dots,2n-1$$

**Second approach**

Multiply by z: 
$$z^{2n+1} = |z|^2$$

When $|z|^2=r^2$ in the trig notation

$$z= \sqrt[2n]{r^2}=\sqrt[2n]{r^2\cis(0)}=r^{2\over2n+1}\cis({2\pi k \over2n+1}), k=0,\dots,2n$$

And of course also 0 is a solution.
Second method gives you one more solution, and none of those look the same.

Comment: The first approach does not describe a solution, just a rewrite of the equation. But no explicit expression of $r$ nor $\theta$. The second approach doesn't solve for $r$.

I wonder how you managed to establish that "none of those look the same".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see now that none are solutions, but I guess we said they're different because we came out with different solutions count?

Comment: @egreg mentioned it at the start :)

Comment: @egreg Oh. Stupid me. Fixed it, thank you <3

Comment: How can you "come out with  different solutions count" when you didn't solve the equation ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust We didn't realize until now that we didn't really solve the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equating the moduli,

$$r^{2n}=r$$ or $$r=0\lor r=1.$$

Equating the arguments,

$$2n\theta=-\theta+2k\pi$$ or $$\theta=\frac{2k\pi}{2n+1}.$$

There are $2n+2$ distinct solutions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why is it possible to have more than 2n solutions?

Comment: @DefinitelyNotaMathematician: why not ?

Comment: Why doesn't the fundamental theorem of algebra apply here?

Comment: @DefinitelyNotaMathematician: because the equation is not algebraic !

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer you a third approach to compare to.

$z^{2n}=r^{2n}e^{2ni\theta}=re^{-i\theta}$

And so $r=1$ clearly. Now solve for values of $\theta$. i.e.
$$e^{(2n+1)i\theta}=1$$

Comment: and "r=0" which gives the z=0 solution? and for what's left, i'm still confused. here I would use De moivre, or just by power comparison (when transforming 1 to euler notation)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the $2n$-th root as late as possible.

In approach 1, you have to remember about $0$, which *is* a solution. If $z\ne0$, then you can write $z=r\cis\theta$ and then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\cis}{cis}
r^{2n}\cis(2n\theta)=r\cis(-\theta)
$$
and therefore
$$
r^{2n-1}\cis((2n+1)\theta)=1
$$
Now we deduce $r=1$ and
$$
(2n+1)\theta=2k\pi \qquad (k=0,1,\dots,2n)
$$

For approach 2, do, instead
$$
|z|^{2n}=|\bar{z}|=|z|
$$
so either $z=0$ or $|z|=1$. In the latter case, $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$ and you get again
$$
z^{2n+1}=1
$$

Comment: Oh that's a really cool solution as well! didn't even think about dividing!

Comment: and thanks for the post fixes :)